# WCF Routing service hangs/CPU spike

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7

we're facing a bit of an issue with a WCF router service feature. The service receives incoming requests over https/custom binding using username over password, decrypts the message, performs authentication and forwards it to a non-https web service. The service has been running fine on one data-center for a couple of years. We're in the process of moving it to a different DC and have hit an issue with a CPU spike and an inordinate delay when responding back to the calling client.

The route is as follows

Client UI (https) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI5ei.jpg)--> Routing Service (decrypt/authenticate) (http) [2]--> main webservice [3]--> Routing Service (https) [4]--> Client UI

The delay happens on step 4 when the router service responds back to the client with the actual response payload.

- There is a several minute delay that happens sporadically while executing step 4. ( Some requests with the exact same payload work fine )
- When there is a hang, there's high CPU usage where 1 core is generally running at 100%
- I turned on tracing in WCF and although the timeline shows a delay in reponse, there is no log message as to where/why. This is with full verbose activity tracing turned on
- The older datacenter where this was running had no delays or CPU spikes

The server is Windows 2008 SP2 with a Xeon E5530 with 192 GB or RAM and the routing service is hosted on IIS. Just to be sure, I ran the gamut of tests, including ANTS performance/memory profiler and Perfmon to rule out any issues with .NET GC or just the .NET framework. The hang happens when invoking something outside of the .NET framework. The only way I was able to get a low level stack trace was after installing the Windows server symbols and using Process Explorer. The stack trace of the thread occupying all of the CPU is below. I created a full dump of the process and loaded it into Windbg and I get the same stack.

From what I've investigated, the delay happens when writing to a device but it's not clear why there's a CPU spike and why the problem is sporadic and not consistent. We ran a complete test on all hardware and there are no errors. There are other web services operating on the same server that handle similar loads and they work absolutely fine without a hint of problem ( ruling out any issues with the n/w ). The server also has multiple NIC's so I disabled the primary and tested it on a different NIC but the problem persisted. If anyone has seen anything similar, any tips would be appreciated. We've also tried complete re-image of the server and install everything from scratch but that didn't help.

[image: Stack trace from Process Explorer]

Comment: This is a hard problem to solve over SO... I would investigate in the direction of Certificates, HTTPS etc. Have you turned on Service Side tracing on WCF? Configure WCF to log everything (trace and message).

Comment: Yes, server side tracing was turned on, and as explained above, I can see the delay in the messages, but there's no indication of what's causing the delay. The stack trace indicates that it's happening outside of the Framework, so I don't expect to see any logs for the reason of the hang.CPU spike. I also suspected a certificate issue or something to do with https traffic, but other web services that use https endpoints work fine.